# how to wait for ui delegate in swift

Tags: ios, swift, messageui

I want to create simple object helper to sending sms in many places on my Swift 2.0 app, and in next step another helpers (email, pdf opener etc)

I create simple class:

```
import Foundation
import MessageUI

class SmsHelper: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func sendSMS(body: String){
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()){
            let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            messageVC.body = body
            //messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            AppDelegate().sharedInstance().getTopController().presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }
        else{
            //do some alert etc.
        }
    }


    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult){
        sendSMSRsp(result, errorMsg: nil)
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print("sms didFinishWithResult")
    }
}
```

in anywhere in code I want to do that:

```
class someAnotherClass{
  func someFunction(){
    let smsHelper = SmsHelper()
    smsHelper.sendSms("some text")
  }
}
```

so sms ios editor is opened, but when I want to close it or sending, it don't dismiss, function `messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult)` i never called and app crashes with memory leak, I know reason: is because SmsHelper object in 'someFunction' is deleting after end scope of this function, and this object is nil, and system try to call didFinishWithResult at nil object. I confirm it: when I add smsHelper object as member of 'SomeClass' it worked - delegate is called.

Question is: What is the best practice to do that, adding a member is not an option for me, because many classes can use that, also creating a singleton, appDelegate member is I think quite stupid. How to force not deleting a object at end of scope function?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use singleton way to do it:

```
class SmsHelper: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
   static let sharedInstance = SmsHelper()
   private init() {}
}
```

And usage:

```
SmsHelper.sharedInstance().sendSms('some text')
```

**EDIT:**
   If you add different init method from abstract class.

```
 private override init(message: String){
        super.init()
    }
```

then change definition to `static let sharedInstance = SmsHelper(message:"smsHelper")` won't complicated.

For your delegate, just assign it out of the `init` method, in the `UIViewController` `viewDidLoad`,

```
SmsHelper.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

Comment: It's worked but probably it's complicated if SmsHelper has a parent with custom constructor, for ex, when I have 3 class: SmsHelper, PdfHelper, EmailHelper, and abstract class Helper who have constructor Helper(body:String) , I start to read about NSOperation, it's possibile to use NSOperation to that?

Comment: Sorry i am lost what you said, but why you need abstract class? If add some methods can get ride of coupling. why not? All the Helper should subclass of NSObject. Just from my point of view. If this answer helps please accept it.

Comment: I see that he describe `also creating a singleton, appDelegate member is I think quite stupid. `

Comment: I explain: I wrote most simple example to create clear question on stackoverflow - in my real code, abstract helper class is needed for two reasons: 1) Have a delegate with caller and constructor Helper(delegate: SomeProtocol) 2) Have abstract method to create JsonResponse f.ex when sms is send or not I create a JSON and send it to delegate for some reasons.

Comment: See my edit. Not sure solved your "complicated" issue.

Comment: If still can't solve your issue maybe it's not suit for singleton design.

Comment: You can't do that: static let sharedInstance = SmsHelper(message:"smsHelper") beacuse it must be dynamic. Of course you can write function like `static func sharedInstance(message: String)` but in all helper (sms,pdf,email) class they must be declared, it's not DRY.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the way to do this is to create a type alis of a closure, then storing an optional variable of this type alias. When you call sendSMS, you pass in a closure and set it to your variable. Then that can be called in the delegate, which will then pass it through the closure of sendSMS:

```
import Foundation
import MessageUI

class SmsHelper: MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    let messageVC: MFMessageComposeViewController!
    typealias SMSCompletion = (result: MessageComposeResult, errorMsg: NSError?) -> ()
    var sendSMSRsp: SMSCompletion?

    func sendSMS(body: String, completion: SMSCompletion){
        sendSMSRsp = completion
        if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()){
            messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
            messageVC.body = body
            //messageVC.recipients = ["Enter tel-nr"]
            messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            AppDelegate().sharedInstance().getTopController().presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

        } else {
            //do some alert etc.
        }
    }


    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult){
        sendSMSRsp?(result: result, errorMsg: nil)
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print("sms didFinishWithResult")
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {

    func someFunction() {
        let smsHelper = SmsHelper()
        smsHelper.sendSMS("some text") { (result, errorMsg) -> () in

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this code will be elegant solution for me but it not worked, 'messageComposeViewController didFinishWithResult'  is never called.

Comment: That sounds like an issue due to the delegate not being set properly. I think you need to create the `MFMessageComposeViewController` outside of the function, i will change my answer to suit.

Comment: As you answer - I move outside MFMessageComposeViewController of the funciton - still not worked and crashed, looks like smshelper object is deleting at end of sendSms scope.